# TypeScript Cannot find name 'Promise' intellisense error

Tags: typescript2.0

I am getting a red squiggly intellisense error in TypeScript 2.1.4, Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 saying **Cannot find name 'Promise'**, for example the following code shows the error on both uses of Promise:

```
/// <reference path="../typings/index.d.ts" />
import 'fetch';
import {HttpClient, json} from 'aurelia-fetch-client';
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {BearerToken} from './common/bearer-token';

export class ApiToken
{
....
    public getTokenSimplified(): Promise<BearerToken>
    {
        let tokenResult: BearerToken;

        let p = new Promise<BearerToken>(function (resolve, reject)
        {
            // my code ommited
        });
        return p;
    }
....
}
```

The TypeScript does compile without an error so I can get by with this, but I'd like to find a solution. Does anyone know how to solve this? Having researched StackOverflow and Github I have tried the following:

- npm install es6-promise --save, and import {Promise} from 'es6-promise' added to the top of the source file

  This does cause the red squiggly to disappear but leads to the build error       "Type Promise is not assignable to type Promise. Two different types with this name exist but they are unrelated."

  Installing and referencing npm's ts-promise incurs the same "Two different types with this name exist" error.
- typings install dt~es6-shim --save --global

  This causes duplicate definitions, e.g. Duplicate identifier 'PropertyKey' in lib.es2015.core.d.ts
- typings install dt~es6-promise --save --global

  This causes error Duplicate identifier 'Promise' in lib.es2015.iterable.d.ts
- typings install bluebird --source npm --save

  This fails with the compile time error "Type Promise is not assignable to type 'Bluebird'" because HttpClient returns Javascript Promises, not Bluebird promises.
- npm install es6-shim --save and npm install @types/es6-shim --save-dev

  This causes duplicate definitions, e.g. Duplicate identifier 'PropertyKey' in lib.es2015.core.d.ts
- npm install es6-promise --save and npm install @types/es6-promise --save-dev

  causes error Duplicate identifier 'Promise' in lib.es2015.iterable.d.ts
- in tsconfig.json, modifying "lib": ["es2015", "dom"] to "lib": ["es2015", "es2015.promise", "dom"] did not fix the problem.

tscconfig.json as follows :

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": "src",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "amd",
    "declaration": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": ["es2015", "dom"],
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "src/*": ["src/*"]
    }
  },
  "filesGlob": [
    "./src/**/*.ts",
    "./test/**/*.ts",
    "./typings/index.d.ts",
    "./custom_typings/**/*.d.ts",
    "./jspm_packages/**/*.d.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "jspm_packages",
    "dist",
    "build",
    "test"

  ],
  "atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": false
  }
}
```

Perhaps I am not referencing the required library correctly so if someone can point out the error I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this config for libs

```
"lib": ["es2015", "dom", "es6"]
```

If other types are missing (`Request`, `Response`, `BufferSource` `URLSearchParams`,...) please send your typings.json file.

Comment: Adding "es6" to tsconfig.json made no difference. There are no other missing types.

Comment: @Alastair 
Promise<T> is defined in lib.es2015.iterable.d.ts 
Path on standard install : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TypeScript\lib.es2015.iterable.d.ts
Are other versions of TypeScript than 2.1.4 installed ?
Did you setup your Aurelia project by Aurelia-CLI ?

Comment: Regarding the TypeScript version: I am using 2.1.4 which is specified in the PATH and also in the project's TypeScriptToolsVersion element. Wnen I installed TypeScript 2.1.4 it installed in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\2.1, however the file you mention also exists. WinMerge shows both files to be virtually identical (the Promise and all other definitions are the same) though the version in Microsoft SDKs also includes a ReadonlyArray<T> interface definition.

Comment: I did not use Aurelia-CLI to setup the project as it is no longer recommended. I tried the following but the intellisense error remained:
"lib": ["es2015", "dom", "es2015.iterable"] and also 
"lib": ["es2015", "dom", "es2015.promise"]

Comment: I setup the project by copying the Aurelia Typescript skeleton v1.1.2 into the root of an ASP.NET MVC project.

Comment: There are other versions of TypeScript installed in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\ : 1.0, 1.7 and 1.8. However I think they are not being referenced as they are not in the PATH or the project's TypeScriptToolsVersion element

Comment: @Alastair
As you can compile without errors, I think its is only an intellisense path problem. There are no missing Libraries for tsc when you compile (see the "Duplicate" problems when you add other definitions).
When you run "tsc -v" from NuGet Package Manager console, the version is 2.1.4 ?
Are you using Resharper ( "Detect TypeScript Version Automatically" feature).
The key is to find the tools that sends the errors and the typings files it uses.

Comment: tsc -v gives Version 2.1.4. I am not using Resharper though I am using Telerik JustCode however I don't think that is related. The Error List window reports the project as "TypeScript Virtual Projects". Thanks for your input, I will persevere, and think this is only an intellisense problem, but would still like to fix it!

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me too. Somehow Intellisense is not picking up the typescript configuration. Just manually point it to your typescript config.

`Setings > Languages & Frameworks > TypeScript`

In the Options field put `-p` plus the path of your project's typescript config e.g. `-p tsconfig.json`